# Access the neo4j browser while running an embedded connection with a bolt connector

Tags: java, neo4j

My project is in Java, and I create an embedded connection to my Neo4j database and add a "bolt" connector to it as described in the documentation here:

http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded

the code is:

```
GraphDatabaseSettings.BoltConnector bolt = GraphDatabaseSettings.boltConnector("0");

graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
    .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(new File("C:/.../default.graphdb"))
    .setConfig(bolt.enabled, "true")
    .setConfig(bolt.address, "localhost:7687")
    .newGraphDatabase();
```

According to the Neo4j documentation I would think that I could now connect to the database using the browser based on "By default, Neo4j Embedded does not expose a Bolt connector, but you can enable one. Doing so allows you to connect the services Neo4j Browser to your embedded instance." However, if I run the code, while I am able to programmatically perform all that I need to, I cannot access the browser at `localhost:7474` nor `localhost:7687`

My question is: Is this just really poorly worded documentation and this is not actually a supported capability? Or is there an undocumented way of connecting to the database through the bolt connection created in the code that would allow me to view the data using the Neo4j browser while running my embedded connection?

Edit:
I am already using the bolt driver library

Comment: Note that I am using Neo4j v 3.0.3, so I cannot use some of the Wrapper solutions available in v2.0

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You need to place the neo4j-bolt-3.0.3 jar in the working directory where your code is executing so that Neo4j can load it. The Bolt connector is a kernel extension.</strike>

I managed to get the Neo4j Browser to connect and work with the embedded instance, by first starting up a Neo4j server (standalone) instance separately and having my web browser cache the Neo4j Browser. Then under the Neo4j Browser settings checking the "Use Bolt protocol when available" setting and setting "Bolt host" to the address of my embedded instance. Then shutting down the standalone server instance. I don't know if it is the supported approach, but seems to work well enough for me.

I have not configured my embedded instance to use authentication.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12875279)

Comment: @cb0 My apologies, you are correct, in haste I misread the question.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i think that setting would enable the browser to actually do the queries over bolt, but wouldnt help with actually having the browser come up since nothing seems to be hosting it.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. One would probably have to do what Neo4j does in the bootstrappers and server (see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/3.1/community/server/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server) to get the embedded instance to serve up the browser. I don't know if there is possibly an easier way to do that though.