# Neo4j Embedded Server and Browser

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I am using Neo4j Embedded 3.1.0.

I would like to able to browse the database using the Neo4j Browser. I have seen [this Stackoverflow question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077512/access-the-neo4j-browser-while-running-an-embedded-connection-with-a-bolt-connec).

## **The first approach:**

I tried several approaches. The first was to use the BOLT connector, that seemed to be a bit confusing. I enabled the BOLT setting on the browser and enabled BOLT on my embedded DB like this:

```
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        GraphDatabaseSettings.BoltConnector bolt = GraphDatabaseSettings.boltConnector( "0" );

    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
            .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( DB_PATH )
            .setConfig( bolt.type, "BOLT" )
            .setConfig( bolt.enabled, "true" )
            .setConfig( bolt.address, "localhost:7687" )
            .newGraphDatabase();

    registerShutdownHook( graphDb );
```

However the browser does not seem to be browsing the data on my embedded server. Sometimes it prompts me for a password. How do I set the password?

Also this approach seems to be launching TWO servers? that would be the first launched along with the desktop application and a second in my embedded application. Is there a way to just launch the browser on it's own?

## **The second approach:**

Point the Neo4j application to my embedded db directory(when my embedded server is not running). This also prompts me for a password. How do I set the password on the DB in this case? is the credentialing info in the DB directory? Or is the login data located elsewhere?

I don't necessarily need to browse while i'm running my embedded server, but it would be nice. The documentation strewn around the web has contradicting recipes and ideas.

Any pointers here? I'm fairly flexible in how I meet this need. I mostly require a powerful way to browse the data for troubleshooting and such.

Comment: This dates a bit but might help http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/11/21/neo4j-browser-with-embedded.html

Comment: thanks, I reviewed that page. This one seems way out of date as it doesn't even mention the BOLT connector.